# Why even try the semantic constraints, if expression can't match the pattern structure?

Tags: programming, evaluation, pattern-matching, language-design

This result is unexpected:

```
Trace[MatchQ[{7}, {_?NumberQ, __}], NumberQ] (* ->  {{NumberQ[7], True}} *)
```

Why evaluate `NumberQ` if the pattern can't conceivably match? What kind of side-effect might change the expression arity during pattern-matching?

Precisely, due to the unbound side-effects and for performance reasons, I would have thought that the matcher would labor very hard to avoid invoking the evaluator.

Note that other cases are not surprising:

```
Trace[MatchQ[{7}, {_?NumberQ, _}], NumberQ] (* -> {} *)

Trace[MatchQ[{7}, {_?NumberQ, ___}], NumberQ] (* ->  {{NumberQ[7], True}} *)
```

The combination of a constraint and `BlankSequence` seems to make the pattern-matcher overly suspicious. So, "*a list of two expressions, first one a number*" bypasses the evaluator; "*a list of two or more expressions, first one a number*" triggers the evaluation of the restriction.

Optimization of pattern-matching is unresolved in general. In the context of expressions in the form **head + n parts**, however, trying to calculate the lower bound of **n** for the class of expressions represented by a pattern strikes me as one of the obvious problems to focus on.

Given the experience of these last weeks, though, the struggle between my intuition and Mathematica is always won by the latter. What am I missing, then?

**Update**:

[Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) and [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) discussed a few years ago about the [uneasy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8484299/618728) [relation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8522876/618728) between the evaluator and the pattern-matcher.

Comment: Which Mathematica are you using? In Mathematica 9.0.1 on Windows I get {} for Trace[MatchQ[{7}, {_?OddQ, __}], NumberQ]

Comment: Mathematica 9.0.1.0/Mac OSX 10.9.2
Well, a Mac bug was last in my list of possible explanations. Can anyone else reproduce the issue?

Comment: FWIW, I got `{}` in both V9.0.0 and the development version (Mac OS X 10.7.5). So it must've been a bug in 9.0.1.

Comment: There is an error in the question that may be confusing people. The first line of code should be `Trace[MatchQ[{7}, {_?NumberQ, __}], NumberQ]`, **not** `Trace[MatchQ[{7}, {_?OddQ, __}], NumberQ]`. I corrected this in the question.

Comment: I also corrected a `BlankSequence`/`BlankNullSequence` confusion.

Comment: @Oleksandr R Thanks a lot, and sorry for the error.
BTW, I got access to a Mathematica 8.0.4.0/Mac OSX 10.8.5 machine and the result is reproducible.

Comment: You are right, it's unnecessary. Note, however, that it could be `{upValuesArePowerful} ^:= {upValuesArePowerful, "and more"}; MatchQ[{upValuesArePowerful}, {_Symbol, __}]`. I suspect proper checking would be more or less equivalent in its complexity to static type cheking for Wolfram language. Even limited suppport of this feature seems to be a true challenge, although I'd be very intetested to know professional's opinion on the topic. It's not clear even if pattern matching wouldn't become impractical then (OTOH it *is* present in Haskell which is typed as strictly as it gets).

Answer (score 3):

This is closely related to my own questions posted a few years ago on Stack Overflow:

- [PatternTest not optimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8484299/618728)
- [Mathematica's pattern matching poorly optimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8522876/618728)

I still am not convinced that some of these patterns could not be better handled but I have come to accept that such things are not likely to change.  Although it can be argued that such methods are "perverse" it can fairly easily be demonstrated that such side-effects can be used.  Consider:

```
i = 0;

count[x_] := (If[x > 0, i++]; True)

Cases[{{1}, {-3}, {2}, {0, 4}}, {_?count, __}, ∞]

i
```

> ```
> {{0, 4}}
>
> 2
> ```

This counts the number of (sub)lists that start with a positive number at the same time as a different match is returned by `Cases`.  Again, I would try to avoid such methods myself, but since these methods *have been* possible changing the language now could have unintended consequences.  At first it might seem that `NumberQ` is safe from such side-effects, but the language allows its redefinition with e.g. `Block` so all bets are off.

I'm afraid such changes might only appear, if ever, in a "reboot" of the language; a kind of "Wolfram Language 2.0" I suppose.  Sadly I think such things are not a priority to the developers, but I do hope to some day see a smaller, cleaner, and faster core language implemented, with a highly optimized pattern matcher, JIT compilation etc.

As a more realistic alternative perhaps it would be possible to introduce a new Head that affects pattern matching (much as `HoldPattern` or `Verbatim` do now) that would declare a pattern to be "pure" and without side-effects, which would trigger additional optimizations.  Nevertheless having to use this Head every time you wanted optimal behavior for patterns that *do not* involve side effects would seem very clumsy.

Comment: When I hit these issues, I recalled having read something related some days ago, but forgot to check the "other" ME. My notes are spotty yet. I'm sorry, will edit the question.

Comment: Yes, the law of unintended consequences is unforgiving. Your example is a neat example of side-effects. What I don't really understand is why `{_?count, __}`  and not `{_?count, _}`. Why "one or more" triggers the evaluator, and "one" not. If Leonid's right (and I think he is), `Blank[]` should also evaluates the constraint.

Comment: @Fallible Actually I missed that part of your question.  I don't know; it does seem inconsistent but I am hesitant to label it a bug without further consideration.

Comment: Another point is that it's only the `Blank*Sequence` forms that show inconsistent behavior. If `Repeated` is used, everything is fine. So, although you certainly have a point that someone might have used this productively in the past, I would really hope that nobody chose such a perverse misfeature as a critical part of their implementation. Anyway, WRI haven't been too coy in changing things where judged necessary, so I wonder how much of a motivation this really is for them.